# ESlint sourced from same location can't load library in different projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions

We have two projects in the same VScode workspace.

`which eslint` revelase `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/eslint` in both cases.

In one project folder, everything works fine.

In another project folder, we get the error:

`The eslint library loaded from /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js doesn't export a CLIEngine. You need at least eslint@1.0.0`

Everything, as far as we can see, is equal. The only different is the project folder.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the ESLint [migration doc](https://eslint.org/docs/8.0.0/user-guide/migrating-to-8.0.0) in version 8 the CLIEngine class has been removed and replaced by the ESLint class.

VS Code ESLint extension has not yet fully adapted to this change. Currently there is insider version [2.1.24-Insider](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/releases/tag/release%2F2.1.24-Insider). That is needed to install manually and it is supposed to work with ESLint v8.

Nevertheless, best you can do is to **wait for next release of VS Code ESLint extension**.

Comment: What a terrible error to throw: "You need at least eslint@1.0.0" 

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem with eslint version 8. I downgraded it to 7.19.0 then it works fine. Try downgrading it.

Comment: ESLint V8 is completely broken in some respect / just for VS Code?

Comment: I am using React. after downgrading to v17.19.0 and running --init. Then choosing React in options. v7.32.0 is upgraded automatically. works with vscode eslint v2.2.2 extension.

Comment: downgrading version,works for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue and I figured out the issue: there was another VSCode extension JS formatter that was trying to use CLIEngine, thus causing the error. I uninstalled all other formatter extensions, but also uninstalled and then reinstalled the dbaeumer.vscode-eslint extension, reloaded VSCode, and finally everything was working.